# Find argc and argv from a library

Tags: c++, c, linux, pointers, argv

How do I find a program's `argc` and `argv` from a shared object?  I am writing a library in C that will be loaded via `LD_PRELOAD`.  I've been able to find the stack two different ways:

1. Read `rsp` via inline `__asm__` call.
2. Read `/proc/<pid>/maps` and parse the entry for stack.

I can then create a pointer, point it at the stack segment, then iterate through looking for data.  The problem is I can't figure out an efficient way to determine what bytes are `argc` and the pointer to the pointer to the `argv` strings.

I know that `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` also contains the arguments, each separated by `0x00`, but I'm interested in finding everything in memory.

In gdb I see a `DWORD` for `argc` followed by a `QWORD` which is the first pointer.  20 bytes before the address of `argc` is a pointer that points back into the main program's code segment.  But that's not a deterministic way to identify `argc` and `argv`.

I've seen a few posts but no working code:

- http://linux.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.os.linux.development.system/2005-07/0296.html
- https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2009-11/msg00010.html

Comment: Seems a bit of a flaky way to do it, being dependent on how the compiler uses the stack. That is likely to change as soon as someone finds a compiler/runtime optimisation. The application may also want to use the same args in a different sense, this could cause problems if your lib tries to interpret params not target ed to it. Can you not pass these directly to your library in a 'constructor' call? Yes, I understand that what you want to do is avoid this overhead.

Comment: At what point the `argc` and `argv` would be accessed? It is probably impossible during `LD_PRELOAD` phase.

Comment: It's also perfectly legitimate for a program to _modify_ the data in `argv`.  I'm not sure what happens to the stack in this case.

Comment: @ChrisR: What overhead, exactly? Calling an initializer?

Comment: @rici - yes, a programming overhead, I should have made that explicit. The code may in fact run faster.

Comment: @ChrisR: Ah, ok. The programming overhead seems minimal to me, certainly less than scanning the stack for something useful. But everyone has their own aesthetic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[This response](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2009-11/msg00006.html) in your second link contains working source code which worked fine for me (Gnu/Linux elf-based system), including during `LD_PRELOAD`.

The code is very short; it consists of a function:

```
int foo(int argc, char **argv, char **env) {
   // Do something with argc, argv (and env, if desired)
}
```

and a pointer to that function in the `.init_array` section:

```
__attribute__((section(".init_array"))) static void *foo_constructor = &foo;
```

Putting that into a shared library and then LD_PRELOADing the shared library certainly triggered the call to `foo` when I tried it, and it was clearly called with the `argc` and `argv` which would later be passed to `main` (and also the value of `environ`).

Comment: Great answer! I'd never thought of running a constructor this way in a library. No fiddling with compiler or run time dependencies. love it. I learn every day.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bad idea, but I'm not naive enough to say you don't have a valid reason for it.

There's no good way to find argc/argv if all you know is the location of the stack. Luckily, `envp` is directly after `argv` on the stack, and every libc that I know of puts `envp` in the `__environ` global. So by going backwards from `__environ`, you can find argc and argv. Here's some example code written in Rust, which should be pretty easy to port to C++:

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub static __environ: *const *const c_char;
}

fn raw_args() -> (c_int, *const *const c_char) {
    let mut walk_environ = unsafe { __environ as *const usize };
    walk_environ = walk_environ.wrapping_offset(-1);
    let mut i = 0;

    loop {
        let argc_ptr = walk_environ.wrapping_offset(-1) as *const c_int;
        let argc = unsafe { *argc_ptr };
        if argc == i {
            break (argc, walk_environ as *const *const c_char);
        }
        walk_environ = walk_environ.wrapping_offset(-1);
        i += 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable is probably to use `/proc/<pid>/cmdline` because that's provided by the kernel and won't change depending on the C implementation (for example it would depend on the processor you're using).

The problem is that on some platforms the arguments to a function (fx `main`) would be passed on the stack, but on other platforms it might be passed as registers (fx on x86-64 platform). If it's sent via registers then if optimizations are enabled `main` will **not** store these in memory if it doesn't need to - that is it's likely not to remain in memory if you don't explicitly do so yourself.

Even if the arguments are passed on the stack the exact location where the arguments of `main` is located may differ from version to version of the compiler/implementation. Which means there's hardly any reliable method of retrieving them from the stack (and as someone pointed out they may be modified during execution of `main` as part of command line parsing).

Even the way the kernel passes the arguments to the program doesn't help much as they are passed via registers - which means that where they're going to be stored is entirely up to the CRT init (which in turn may change from version to version).

In short retrieving `argv` and `argc` later on requires explicit support from the CRT you're using (Microsoft's CRT does that, but GNU doesnt AFAIK).

What you **could** do of course is to grab the source of GCC and patch the CRT init to actually store the `argv` and `argc` somewhere where you can later retrieve them. That would of course not work if you need to access them before CRT init of the program is being run (fx during dynamic linking).